# How do I stretch the control to fill Canvas in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, canvas, stretch

What I need to do is to stretch the control to fill entire Canvas.
I think I have to use a Canvas (I don't want my control to be clipped
when rendered outside the container - as far as I know all the other containers
perform clipping - Grid, Border... - maybe there is another solution?)

If I put the control inside Canvas it works fine (I mean it is not clipped).
However, it doesn't fill entire Canvas.
I was trying to bind to the Canvas width and height - with no results.

Do you have any ideas or clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tested in Kaxaml, and Grid doesn't clip its children by default (though you can make it clip by setting ClipToBounds to true).

Comment: @Joe, I was trying to use Grid and always got a clipped control. Could you provide a code snippet foryour example?

Comment: Here's the XAML I tried: `<Grid Width="80" Height="50" Background="Red"><Button Margin="-10 10" Content="Text"/></Grid>` The Button extends outside the Grid, and doesn't get clipped -- so your concern about "all the other containers perform[ing] clipping" doesn't seem to apply, unless there are details you didn't include.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A control can escape the container such as a `Border` or a `Grid` by having negative margins.  So perhaps you should return to using a `Grid` and play around with placement using column and row definitions and using negative margins where you need them.

Comment: I place a control with a specified height, which can be changed (the control is expanded), and I still want to display entire control (the original control's region + expanded region).

Comment: @Jamie: You need to make choice, do you want to manually place and size the controls or do you want some help from the Grid system?  Why has the "Grid" got a fixed size if you want the content to expand its size?  Why not just let the grid be the total size of its content?